# Electricity Demand Forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have data of past 1 year at 15 minute intervals and corresponding demand data, i need to forecast the data for next day, if i use time series in R should i create 96 models for each block or can 1 model efficiently extract the multiple seasonality in data?

Comment: how do you come up with 96 models?

Comment: I saw in Rob J Hyndman's MEFM package that he is creating 48 hourly models, so i am trying to correlate the same to my case where data is measured at 15 minute interval, instead of half hour.